# Apache access outside local network

Tags: apache-http-server, lan, port

I have an Apache Web Server on my computer (192.168.0.115) inside a local network. I have set port forwarding on router DIR-300 to redirect traffic on ports 80 and 443 to 192.168.0.115. People outside my LAN cannot acces my website. Apache is running on Fedora 17 and I've checked firewall - ports 80 and 443 are open. What's the problem then?

Comment: can you post your IP address?

Comment: I check my public IP from another computer, outside LAN. 3 people checked my website - nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rememer to move your computer outside firewall - to DMZ in router. This provide you to avoid problems like mine.

Comment: So did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Many ISPs block port 80 and 443, apparently as a way to enforce TOS and prevent systems from being used as malware hosts. You would probably want to check if these ports are blocked - [shieldsup](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) is a web based tool to check if specific ports are accessible from outside.

Comment: Port 80 and 443 are green.

Answer (score 0):

Which ip address are you trying to connect to from outside? 192.168.0.115 is incorrect. Instead you should find your public facing ip address and use that outside your LAN.

http://www.whatismyip.com/

Once you have your public ip try connecting to your site with

http://{YOURPUBLICIPADDRESS}

Comment: Of course I tried connect via public IP. I didn't write it here becose it's obvious. I don't have any proxy or nothing.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend. Its not the first time somebody on this site has tried to do connect to a webserver with a local IP